# Particle System Dupli Object's Children Not Rendered

Tags: particles

I have a model which consists of a few levels of parent/child relations, with a single common ancestor `P` at the top. I'd like to set up a particle system which emits instances of the whole model, but when I set the dupli object to `P`, it emits *only `P`*.

It's going to get ugly if I have to join all of the objects into a single mesh.. Is it possible for a particle system to emit a parent with all of its children?

Comment: I'm afraid this is going to be a duplicate question.. I've found it tough to search for, as since regular particle children are hogging the google hits..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group all the objects and under the particles render tab set the render to Group and check whole_group.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 2.81, this is now done with Collections instead of Groups. Be sure to select the checkbox "Whole Collection".

In this example "doughnut" is the parent object, which has a number of child objects:

[image]

Comment: How about I have 2 objects with children, and spawn those two objects randomly? It's not working with collections. For collections it's just listing all objects inside it (even though they are parented to empty). It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I'm so confused. When checking the whole collection for a particle system, the particles are no longer emitted from the actual emitter, but from some sort of offset between the emitter and the object. Any idea why?