# Particle system: How to place random objects with children?

Tags: particles, groups, dupli-groups

I'm trying to place a group of trees that include an armature and leaves in a separate mesh scattered over a land. The problem is that only the tree's base is placed by the particle system, even though the leaves are a direct child of the base (see screenshot):

[image: Particle problem]

The first 3 trees in the middle are placed manually, the other ones are being placed by a particle system, as you can see, without leaves.

I found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19672/20394), but it uses 'whole group' to tie objects together. The problem I then have is that I can't create a 'list' of trees to place at random. I wanted to comment on said answer instead of making my own question but I didn't have enough reputation to do so.

What would be the best way to use the particle system to place random objects such that I can still use objects with children? Thanks!

Other reasons for using Particle System:

- I can use a mask to distribute trees manually (like [this guy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6nKz.jpg))

Comment: Please state your experience with Python.  How many trees are being placed?  Are they relatively static?

Comment: This is a known [situation] with particles.  Python can address this or systems which use Python.  Children are not necessarily copied with particles or animated. Yet you could coordinate animated groups via Python to use the location and rotation and size et cetera of Particles.

Comment: If you are in the favorable position of having a few trees and need immediate results I would place them manually. (No Particles) I have placed animated objects using Particle information. Yet we still need to know your Python experience. Also you might want to state if you want a pre made solution ... or you want to learn something by building your own solution with Python or tools using Python.  Lastly there are tools that do crowd animation ... where your trees could be the crowd ... you may want to search for such add ons.  I have not used them and cannot remember the names at this time.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger my Python experience is highly proficient, are you suggesting I'll try using Python? (I was thinking about it, but hoped for a more integrated solution)

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger there aren't many trees to be placed but it's nice to know how it works in case I do need to place more of them, also I like it better when placed at random rather than doing it myself, as somehow the results seem more favorable.

Comment: Many people have seen this deficiency in the past.  Particles do not seem to copy hierarchies.  I have used Python or something like Python [?] to deal with this.  Yet I still had to manage copying a heirarchy which seems to be best documented and observable by Blender duplicate mechanism.  So my goal in the past was a little Python exploration and getting results.  The duplicated items in my past example were animated with a particular style.  I was willing to pay programming time for that style.  Please state how much animation your trees exhibit.

Comment: My current belief is the addon may serve your needs. If searched and found, you would become that expert because I did not use the add one.  Blender Particles system is not intended for highly animated where each particle has some independent organic movement.  So if you can find that addon or another addon that is a reasonable approach.   Particle systems with visual dust have less scrutiny than tree swaying in the wind perhaps.  You may not be using  some features of particles such as collision.  My comments above about using some readable attributes of the particles system are still valid.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger they currently just have an armature. I didn't start on animations yet, I wanted to experiment with a slight wind.

I was thinking of making a python script that "replaces" dummy particles (i.e cubes) with a full copy of said tree (with children). I think that might be the best way to solve this, especially since there doesn't seem to be an integrated way to do this.